# Keeping record of foreign key fields selected in Python Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, backend

For a project I have a two model Food and Profile. Each day one profile is created.When users adds forr the food_selected field is updated.Everytime I update the food_selected field in profile I want to keep a record of it. So that I can show all the food selected for a single day

```
 class Food(models.Model):
            name = models.CharField(max_length=200 ,null=False)
            def __str__(self):
               return self.name
            
  class Profile(models.Model):
        food_selected = models.ForeignKey(Food,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
```

How can i solve this problem.
Thank You

Comment: Have a look at Django's [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/).

Comment: I am looking into it. But I am having difficulty for storing all the food_selected field like if I use list to store then when I quit server and launch again list gets empty.Should I use another database field to store ? Thank You

Comment: Yes, indeed. You can create another database model or field and store it in there.